# calling Cplex within vb.net

Tags: vb.net, settings, cplex

I have VB.net 2010 and Cplex 12.5 installed on my laptop. I got a console application that calls cplex to model and solve a problem. This app works without problems.

I generate another new console application and I copy paste the whole contents of the first app to the new one. I add all the references exactly as in the first file, but the new application fails with the following error message:

> "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"

error on this line:

```
 dim cplex as new Cplex()
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *incorrect format* exception indicates that the new application 32/64 bit configuration does not match a library that you are calling, most likely the CPLEX library. Compare the configuration of the new application to the old one. Right-click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and select *Configuration Manager...*. Select a configuration in the drop-down in the upper-left corner. Note the Platform that is selected for you project. This must match any libraries that you call.

Comment: would you please instruct me how to check 32/64 bit configuration? When I right click on the solution, there is no "configuration manager". There is a "properties" option that opens the project properties.
I checked all the threads in properties window for the two applications and they are all the same.
I think the problem is that in the new application, I need to address the licence key of my CPLEX installation. but I dont know how.

Comment: Configuration Manager is the 5th item on my VS. Is Configuration Manager listed in the drop-down that is on the toolbar near the *Start* button?

Comment: If you have Windows 8 or 10, the Task Manager will indicate 32-bit applications on the Processes tab. Run the old (working) application to see if *(32 bit)* is included in the application name.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I did every thing suggested here, the two files are the same in everything but the new app is not functioning.

Comment: I am using Win 7 - 64b and dotNET4 
in the process tab, (in win 7) both are mentioned vshost.exe *32
You know, if I should add the licence key of CPLEX somewhere in my application?

Comment: I believe that an incorrect format can occur between an AnyCPU and an x86 (32-bit) library, even if the Prefer 32-bit box is check. I would recommend trying to change the Configuration Platform to x86. You will probably have to "Add" it in order to select it in the Configuration Manager dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

In your IDE , click on `"My Project"` and then on the left on the second tab "`Compile`".

`Prefer "32 Bit"` checked? If not, check it.

-Target CPU should be `AnyCPU`.

.Net Framework - have you set it to the same .Net Framework Version?

Did you write

```
Option Strict on
```

and `Option Infer Off` in your Code?.

Comment: I verified. Both are using the same .net framework.
in both apps, option strict is off. changing it to on results in a lot of errors (in both)